# Trying to fill out a website form using java, but form tag is embedded in iframe tag

Tags: java, html, iframe, jsoup, httpurlconnection

My goal is to access this url http://eaacorp.com/find-a-dealer and fill out a form using java. To do this, I attempted to find all form tags:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HttpUrlConnectionExample{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://eaacorp.com/find-a-dealer").get();
        String page = document.toString();//this is the whole page's html

        Elements formEl = document.getElementsByTag("form");
    }

}
```

However formEl returns empty because the form tag is embedded in the http://www.eaacorp.com/dealer/searchdealer.php html in iframe tag (snippet of page's source):

```
<iframe id="blockrandom" name="iframe" src="http://www.eaacorp.com/dealer/searchdealer.php" width="100%" height="500" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" class="wrapper"></iframe>
```

Hence, is there a way to access the form tag within the iframe tag? Something like:

```
if(formEl.isEmpty()){
    //find iframe
    Elements iframeEl = document.getElementsByTag("iframe");
    System.out.println(iframeEl);
    String embedURL = iframeEl.getSrc();//DOES NOT COMPILE, getSrc() is not a method
    Document embedDoc = Jsoup.connect(embedURL).get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for your own `getSrcString` method, especially since the substring approach will break for minimal changes in the tag.

Use `.attr("abs:src")` on an element with the `src` attribute instead (compare: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls)

**Example Code**

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://eaacorp.com/find-a-dealer").get();
Element iframeEl = document.select("iframe").first();
String embedURL = iframeEl.attr("abs:src");
Document embedDoc = Jsoup.connect(embedURL).get();

System.out.println(embedDoc.select("form").first());
```

**Truncated Output**

```
<form action="findit.php" method="post" name="dlrsrchfrm" target="_blank"> 
    <div style="padding: 15px;">
    [...]
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that you could actually make your own method that can get the src url using substrings and then just use that String to get a document connection:

```
public static String getSrcString(String html){
    String construct = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < html.length() - 5;i++){
        if (html.substring(i, i + 5).equals("src=\"")){
            i += 5;
            while(!html.substring(i, i + 1).equals("\"")){
                construct += html.substring(i, i + 1);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return construct;
}
```

and then in the main:

```
String embedURL = getSrcString(iframeEl.toString());
Document embedDoc = Jsoup.connect(embedURL).get();
```